# Calculate the circle perimeter

Tags: geometry, circles

I would like please some help with the following Geometry problem:
We have a circle and two chords (which are perpendicular to each other). One chord is 3 cm and the other 4 cm.
Calculate the circle's perimeter.

I think that we are able to find the circle's radius through Pythagoras' Theorem. Am I right?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do the chords meet at a common endpoint? If so have 3-4-5 triangle to start with.

Comment: Can you sketch it? How did you attempt?

Comment: With "vertical Each other" you presumably mean they are perpendicular?

Comment: If there is nothing known about the intersection point of the chords the only possible statement is that the circle perimeter is larger than $4\pi$ cm.

Answer (score 0):

Diameter is 5 by Pythagoras thm and perimeter $5 \pi $ if the two segments connect at their common end-point.